# ios 8 Locationmanager not asking for permission

Tags: ios, ios8, cllocationmanager

I can't get LocationManager to work with IOS8, i've added the two new values to plist and i do the request. But it still does not work. What am i doing wrong?

Plist: [image]

This is my code:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];


locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;

[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

float latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
float longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
```

I get no request for permission.

Comment: Have you tried remove your app from simulator/device and Build&Run again?

Comment: Yes, still no question

Answer (score 1):

First try remove your app from simulator/device.

Then Change your authorization line to:

```
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [[[LocationManager sharedInstance] locationManager] requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

Add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to your plist (try it with/without WhenInUseUsageDescription as the second).